# Looking for Russian science-fiction short story

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

Read this story in an anthology of Russian sci-fi. It features two scientists intent on traveling into the sun for research. One is very mathematically precise and uptight, the other believes in the power of imagination etc. On their way to the sun, the "right brain" scientist starts singing old folk songs to calm his nerves, which the "left brain" scientist tells him is stupid, although he sees they have to work together to properly calibrate their ship. Symbolically, by the time they fly safely out of the sun, both are singing. 
If anyone can give me the name of the story OR the author, that would be fantastic!

Comment: What language did you read it in?

Answer (score 12):

It is a story by a famous Russian writer and inventor Genrikh Altov (Генрих Альтов) (pen name, real name [Genrich Altschuller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genrich_Altshuller)), [“Icarus and Daedalus”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?954787) (Икар и Дедал), published in his first collection *[Star Captains Legends*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?31452) (Легенды о звёздных капитанах), 1961.  I may still have a copy.